# Attempting to call player a table value

Tags: lua, love2d

I am writing my first lua script with love2d and I am not sure why I am getting the error "main.lua:4 attempting to call global 'Player' a table value". My 2 scripts are below:
**--Main.lua**

```
require("player")
function love.load()
  p = Player()
end

function love.update(dt)
  p:update(dt)
end

function love.draw()
  p:draw()
end
```

**--Player.lua**

```
  Player = {}
    --variables for the player (size, position, speed)

function Player:new()
  o = {
    x = 30,
    y = 30,
    w = 20,
    h = 20,
    speed = 300,
      }
  setmetatable(player, { __index = Player })
end

function Player:update(dt)
  if love.keyboard.isDown("a") then
    player.x = player.x - player.speed * dt
  end
  if love.keyboard.isDown("d") then
    player.x = player.x + player.speed * dt
    end
  if love.keyboard.isDown("w") then
    player.y = player.y + player.speed * dt
    end
  if love.keyboard.isDown("s") then
    player.y = player.y - player.speed * dt
    end
  end

function Player:draw()
  love.graphics.rectangle("fill", o.x, o.y, o.w, os.h)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `Player` table, implementing some class. That's a table, you shouldn't call it like `p = Player()`. Call the `new()` method instead:

```
function love.load()
  p = Player:new()
end
```

Also, it seems there's bugs in that `new()` too. You declare global `o` variable (should be local really), and you return `player` instead of `o`, and there's no `player` there at all. Fix it like this:

```
function Player:new()
  local player = {
    x = 30,
    y = 30,
    w = 20,
    h = 20,
    speed = 300,
      }
  return setmetatable(player, { __index = Player })
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, your suggestion fixed the first error but another one showed up on line 8 in the love.update function. "Attempt to index global 'p' a nil value

Comment: I showed a fix, but that fix has a bug too :) The last line should read `return setmetatable(player, ... blah-blah)`. You've created an object, set its metatable, but didn't return it from the constructor. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid global variables like Player in `player.lua`, this is asking for trouble

This should work:

main.lua

```
local player = require("player")

function love.load()
  p = player:new()
end

function love.update(dt)
  p:update(dt)
end

function love.draw()
  p:draw()
end
```

player.lua

```
 local Player = {}

function Player:new()
  local player = {
    x = 30,
    y = 30,
    w = 20,
    h = 20,
    speed = 300,
    }
  self.__index = self
  return setmetatable(player, self)
end

function Player:update(dt)
  if love.keyboard.isDown("a") then
    self.x = self.x - self.speed * dt
  end
  if love.keyboard.isDown("d") then
    self.x = self.x + self.speed * dt
    end
  if love.keyboard.isDown("w") then
    self.y = self.y + self.speed * dt
    end
  if love.keyboard.isDown("s") then
    self.y = self.y - self.speed * dt
    end
  end

function Player:draw()
  love.graphics.rectangle("fill", self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)
end

return Player
```